# Geoserver bottleneck when writing response image

Tags: geoserver, wms

I've come across a bottleneck that occurs when writing the final png file from a WMS request. I'm rendering a geotiff (tiled, LZW compressed, with external overviews, 90 MB file), reprojecting the layer from native CRS to EPSG:4326. When requesting an image of the same size in native CRS, the request takes around 100 ms, when reprojected, the request takes on average around 7000 ms.

I had a look in logs with GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER_LOGGING options and both requests (native/reprojected) are taking similar amount of time except when writing the final png output image, where the request for reprojected image gets stucked:

```
2022-10-18 14:12:02,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ...
2022-10-18 14:12:09,139 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ... done!
```

Using these log messages, I was able to look up following function in java:

```
    public void formatImageOutputStream(
            RenderedImage image, OutputStream outStream, WMSMapContent mapContent)
```

As I'm not sure what this function does, could anyone advise me where to look next? The server is a virtual machine with Windows Server running in HyperV, multiple cores and plenty of memory allocated to java. The issue seems to be affecting all layers, however same rasters and layers are working fine in other Geoserver instances that I run on physical machines.

Thanks a lot.

Geoserver version: 2.20.2
Container: Tomcat 9.0 (jre1.8.0_321)

Comment: this would be better discussed on the geoserver-users mailing list

Comment: Thanks Ian, I've forwarded the issue to that mailing list.